Формирование sql запроса
Читал документацию Товары и CIBlockElement::GetList. В начале статьи был приведен оператор
$iterator = \CIBlockElement::GetList(
    array(),
    array('IBLOCK_ID' => 2),
    false,
    false,
    array('ID', 'NAME', 'IBLOCK_ID')
);

Он переводится в следующий sql запрос
SELECT  BE.ID as ID,BE.NAME as NAME,BE.IBLOCK_ID as IBLOCK_ID
FROM b_iblock B
INNER JOIN b_lang L ON B.LID=L.LID
INNER JOIN b_iblock_element BE ON BE.IBLOCK_ID = B.ID
WHERE 1=1 
    AND (
        ((((BE.IBLOCK_ID = '2'))))
    )
    AND (((BE.WF_STATUS_ID=1 AND BE.WF_PARENT_ELEMENT_ID IS NULL)))

Объясните мне, как был сформирован этот sql запрос.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! SQL запрос соответствует заданным условиям в вызове \CIBlockElement::GetList() и переведен на sql, уточните ваш вопрос, что именно вам не понятно. Если возникнут сложности, ознакомьтесь со справкой, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Установи себе исходные коды версии битрикса и смотри как оно там устроено. На худой конец исследуй исходники на https://bxapi.ru/
